# XSLT How to traverse cdata section that contains xml

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, cdata

input:

```
<store xmlns="test">
    <item>book</item>
    <info><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0"?><value xmlns="value">
<price>11</price>
</value>]]>
    </info>
</store>
```

I want the output like below

```
<value xmlns="value">
    <item>book</item>
    <price>11</price>
</value>
```

Can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> Can i achieve this?

**Not in pure XSLT 1.0 or even XSLT 2.0.**

If you wait to have an XSLT 3.0 XSLT processor (still a W3C WD (Working draft)), then you'd be able to use a function called **[`parse-xml()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml)** to parse the text node child of `info` into a separate XML document.

In XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 you need to write an extension function, which when passed a string (like the value of `info`, parses it as XML and returns the parsed XmlDocument back to the transformation.